# How to make the rollover stick once clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, sprite

I'm having a navigation out of buttons, that are using image sprites.
I want them to stay "rolled over" once they are clicked (even when changing sites). And they should roll back to normal, when they are clicked again.

I'm really new to javascript, but there sure is a way to make it work.

One button looks like this:

```
<a class="contact" href="#" >Contact</a>
```

And the css, to make them roll:

a.contact {

```
display: block;  
width: 30px;  
height: 31px;
margin-right:39px;
float:right;
background: url(../img/navcontact.png) no-repeat bottom;
text-indent: -10000px;
```

}

a:hover.contact {

```
background-position: 0 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Here is the Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/VLqq6/

Comment: Great, it works! But what do I have to add, to make it return to class contact (normal), when clicked again?
Also, will this stick, if I change the page? Guess I'd have to save it in a cookie then?! How do I do that?

Comment: Actually, I believe it would have to return to normal depending on what page I am. Or what is shown..

Comment: Cause, if I have e.g multiple links (navi icon, link on site), the do the same (in my case: show a div). And say, I click the link, (my div opens) and I click the navi to hide the div again, the navi icon will be "active", which is not desired.
Also in another case, I would click on an navi icon, to switch the page, but I wont click the icon again, to switch back. So the script somehow needs to check, on which page I am, or what div is shown.
Sorry, to bother you that much!

Comment: You can do it with css selectors -
$('div').live('click', function(){
    $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
})

Comment: See for yourself: test.unleashedart.com (click @ icon in navi; click link: "contact me".) It has to be more like: click navi icon; div opens; navi icon active; click navi icon again; div hides; navi icon normal.
Click site link; div opens; navi icon not active; click site link again; div hides. <-- Until here it works, except, that the icon would have to be active then too.
But: click site link; div opens; navi icon not active; click e.g. navi icon; navi icon active; div closes. <--Undesireable.